# How do you rig nunchucks for character animation?

Tags: rigging

I tried to add an armature and IK system to a simple nunchucks models I made. I didn't want a real world physics for the chain, as that won't serve the complex character (combatant) animation.

I couldn't make a rig that can be controlled from two different grips. I don't want to use the curve deform for the chain in the middle cause it's too glitchy for an extensive animation (I believe).

Does anyone know how to rig nunchucks for sophisticated combat animations?

Comment: Look into using empties to parent sections of an object.

Comment: Maybe create a root bone in the middle of the chain and two IK "arms"?